# IOS Swift CNContactViewController Navigation Bar Not Showing UINavigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, cncontactviewcontroller

I have been working on this problem for a bit but can't get anything to work.
I have a view controller that effectively stands along in the main story board. Inside that view controller, when a specific action occurs that passes a contact type to the action.

The action opens a new contact view controller for the contact passed, and allows the user to interact with the contact per the CNContactViewController. 
Once the user is done with the contact, it will close, because of the didCompleteWith method, but there is no way to exit the contact controller, without actually creating the contact.

```
//change to new contact screen
let con = CNMutableContact()
con.givenName = familyComponents[0]
con.familyName = familyComponents[1]

let newEmail = CNLabeledValue(label: "Personal", value: objectComponents[2] 
as NSString)
con.emailAddresses.append(newEmail)
con.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(
label: "Home", value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: objectComponents[3])))
let newScreen = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: con)
newScreen.message = "Made using  app"
newScreen.contactStore = CNContactStore()
newScreen.delegate = self
newScreen.allowsActions = true
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: 
newScreen)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have tried everything from navigationItems to navigationItems, it seems to me that the navigation bar is there, because it is possible to change its translucency with this line of code:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Methods Below:

```
func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, 
didCompleteWith contact: CNContact?) {
    viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    inContact = false
}
func contactViewController(_ shouldPerformDefaultActionForviewController: 
CNContactViewController, shouldPerformDefaultActionFor property: 
CNContactProperty) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I have been struggling with this problem for too long. 
Thanks!

SOLVED:
Got it to work. Turns out that this is a bug in apples framework. To solve this problem I just switched it from Unknown Contact to New Contact, which apparently does not have this bug. 
Part of new code:

```
let newScreen = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: con)
newScreen.delegate = self
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newScreen)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thanks

Comment: after didcomplete not showing the navigation or before?

Comment: Before did complete, not showing the navigationbar, I need alternate method to cancel besides did complete.

Answer (score 1):

can you try with this code

```
let con = CNMutableContact()
con.givenName = familyComponents[0]
con.familyName = familyComponents[1]

let newEmail = CNLabeledValue(label: "Personal", value: objectComponents[2] 
as NSString)
con.emailAddresses.append(newEmail)
con.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(
label: "Home", value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: objectComponents[3])))
let unkvc = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: con)

                                unkvc.delegate = self
                                unkvc.allowsEditing = true
                                unkvc.allowsActions = true
                                unkvc.title = "Edit Contact"

    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(unkvc, animated: false)
```

Comment: Thank you! My problem was in hidden NavigationBar for current navigationController

Comment: not work in my case